# Within the reddit comment datasets - which were the posts that rose to 1000 comments the fastest?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, reddit

From https://www.reddit.com/r/datasets/comments/3icas8/reddit_july_comments_are_now_available/cuiahh9?context=3

Which submissions ramped up the fastest? (Which submissions reached their 1,000th comment in N seconds -- sorted by N ascending). Basically ranking submissions by acceleration with regards to comment volume. (I'm assuming breaking news stories would be the fastest ones).

Answer (score 2):

Let's rank the comments for each post by time posted, look at the 1st and 1000th, take the time difference between both and order by that:

```
SELECT link_id, FIRST(IF(rank=1000,created_utc,null)) - FIRST(IF(rank=1,created_utc,null)) thousand
FROM (
  SELECT link_id, created_utc, RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY link_id ORDER BY created_utc) rank
  FROM [fh-bigquery:reddit_comments.2015_07] 
)
WHERE rank=1000 OR rank=1
GROUP BY link_id
HAVING NOT thousand IS null
ORDER BY thousand
```

Fastest:

https://www.reddit.com/r/leagueoflegends/comments/3epmvx/spoiler_team_liquid_vs_team_impulse_na_lcs_2015/[1]

Slowest:

https://www.reddit.com/r/Lollapalooza/comments/3054px/official_2015_rlollapalooza_ticket_resale_thread/[2]

3rd place:

https://www.reddit.com/r/announcements/comments/3djjxw/lets_talk_content_ama/[3]